# Is it good practice to delete columns that are not required from entity framework 6 generated models?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework-6

Is it good practice to delete properties (columns) that are not required from entity framework 6 model that is auto generated using database first approach? If not then what is the alternative.

Please explain.

Answer (score 1):

It is not a a good idea. The model generated is a representation of your database.  Rather re-design your database tables to include only the columns you want. If you delete the properties from the  code-generated  model the schema will be wrong and you will run into problems.

If you do not want to delete the database columns, then you can use code first and map your model to the existing database columns.